# Entity Framework How to fill NotMapped Property that need a join?

Tags: c#, join, entity-framework-6

I have a PostInfo table and LikeInfo Table,PostInfo have list of LikeInfo (for post likes).PostInfo table have a NotMapped property named of "LikeCount".
I want select list of PostInfoes and join to LikeInfo table and calcualte count of LikeInfoes of post and fill count of this to LikeCount property.

Here is my sample:

```
        var query = context.PostInfoes.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Include(x => x.LikeInfoes);
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            item.LikeCount = item.LikeInfoes.Count;
        }
        return query.ToList();
```

That is not good way for me because I do foreach on query and set LikeCount manualy **however I dont want/need include full peoperties of LikeInfo table in this case**.

I'm finding the best and easy way to fill this property.

Comment: It seems you need to use `join` for this purpose.

Comment: yes,but problem in join i search is i must do .Select(x => new PostInfo() { LikeCount = x.LikeInfoes.Count }); and it is not good way I must fill all of another data manualy?

Comment: You can convert the LikeCount to a calculated field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since EF6 does not allow projecting to entity type, you need to use LINQ to Entities query with intermediate anonymous type projection containing all necessary data, then switch to LINQ to Objects (via `AsEnumerable()`) and do the final projection, using a delegate block to perform the necessary unmapped property fixups:

```
var result = context.PostInfoes
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .Select(x => new { Info = x, LikeCount = x.LikeInfoes.Count() })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.Info.LikeCount = x.LikeCount;
        return x.Info;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Monah Lol, after `AsEnumerable()` - yes! But before that (the `IQueryable` part) is creating and executing database query.

Comment: thank you,i think this is best way cuz: no double query and lazy foreach in query, just use a trick :)

Comment: Thank you!  I love this solution as it allows you to add unmapped properties to an EF entity but still ensure its set by your queries so you are never working with "partially filled objects."  I'm envisioning being able to use this for API calls that have optional "include" type statements and then have unmapped nullable properties that will only be set when they're requested.  This would be great for counts and other meta info that is otherwise not needed. It even ensures that the entities are still tracked so they're not projections. Beautiful.   Exactly what I was looking for.